# Visual Studio is not loading my debugger visualizer

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, debuggervisualizer

I wrote my own Debugger Visualizer.

It, and the attributes, are in their own assembly.  There is no references or attributes in the assembly containing the class to be debugged - I want to make a drop-in dll that is optional for people to use.

The class I am trying to debug is a generic.

```
[Serializable]
public class FinCellTable<S> : IFinCellTable, IEnumerable<List<FinCell.IFinCell>>
    where S : class, FinCell.IFinHeaderCell, FinCell.IFinCell, new()
```

Here is the visualizer:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(
        typeof(Financials.Debugging.CellTableVisualizer),
        typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
        Target = typeof(Financials.Transformation.IFinCellTable),
        Description = "FinCell Table Visualizer")]
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(
        typeof(Financials.Debugging.CellTableVisualizer),
        typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
        Target = typeof(Financials.Transformation.FinCellTable<Financials.FinCell.FinHeaderCell>),
        Description = "FinCell Table Visualizer")]

namespace Financials.Debugging
{
    public class CellTableVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            if (windowService == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("windowService");
            if (objectProvider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("objectProvider");

            var data = (IFinCellTable)objectProvider.GetObject();
            using (var displayForm = new CellTableVizForm())
            {
                displayForm.PopulateForm(data);
                windowService.ShowDialog(displayForm);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am running Visual Studio 2010, and the following directory contains the .dll and .pdb of the Visualizer Assembly:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers
```

I place a breakpoint on an instance of IFinCellTable that is specifically FinCellTable.  It does not show the magnifying glass.

I debugged Visual Studio using another Visual Studio as the first VS was debugging.  I watched the output window as the first VS loaded dll's.  When I triggered a visualizer on a datatable, the second VS outputted that it loaded Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DataSetVisualizer.dll (the latter from the correct directory I said above).  (The Modules window behaves/shows the same.)

So obviously my Debugger Visualizer Drop-In assembly is not be loaded by VS, so it doesn't know to show the magnifying glass.

How do you get visual studio to load Visualizers up-front, so drop-in visualizers *work* and you don't need to edit your original code?

Comment: Nothing jumps out.  You *did* restart VS after copying the visualizer, right?

Comment: Do you need to do some sort of UI or environment reload?  This was required for add-ons in prior versions.

Comment: Strange. I did exactly what you describe here: http://www.adamjamesnaylor.com/HowToWriteADebugVisualiserInVisualStudio.aspx and it seemed to work ok. As Michel asks, are you sure it's in the correct folder? I ask because at work my Visual Studio User folder is on a network share and VS throws security exceptions when trying to access off the share.

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess: are you sure the correct files are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`, not in `C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers`?

If yes, that's due to [UAC Virtualization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681).

Answer (score 1):

This question is over 5 years old, so I assume it's no longer relevant to the original poster, but for anyone else trying to do something similar:

System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer does not work when target is an interface.  You have to specify a concrete type.  You have to specify the attribute on every single concrete type you want to visualize:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer("Financials.Debugging.CellTableVisualizer, Financials.Debugging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...")]
[Serializable]
public class FinCellTable<S> : IFinCellTable, IEnumerable<List<FinCell.IFinCell>>
    where S : class, FinCell.IFinHeaderCell, FinCell.IFinCell, new()
{
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be disabled in Tools > Options: 
If you do not see the effects of DebuggerDisplay or DebuggerTypeProxy ensure that Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Show raw structure of objects in variables windows is NOT checked.

Answer (score 0):

The correct folder to place it is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers. Once you place this DLL there and restart visual studio then you should get a "magnifying glass" over "Expression" type of variables (in debugging mode you will get it in watch window and also when you move your mouse cursor over the variable)